# Pandas to_csv for multiple rows/timestamps of the same symbol

Tags: python, pandas

I am fetching a constant stream of data into a dataframe, which I now need to save into multiple CSVs.

For example,
I am fetching OHLCV data from Binance and I get this dataframe:

```
                             sym              o              h              l  \
2024-02-09 11:15:59.594  ETHUSDT  2419.56000000  2479.88000000  2419.16000000   

                                     c                v  barcomplete  
2024-02-09 11:15:59.594  2471.79000000  170696.13700000        False  
                            sym           o           h           l  \
2024-02-09 11:15:59.622  IDUSDT  0.54534000  0.64866000  0.53587000   

                                  c                  v  barcomplete  
2024-02-09 11:15:59.622  0.60634000  93122120.00000000        False  
                             sym            o            h            l  \
2024-02-09 11:15:59.658  ICPUSDT  12.18600000  12.81000000  12.16500000   

                                   c                 v  barcomplete  
2024-02-09 11:15:59.658  12.62300000  1065607.61000000        False  
                             sym              o              h              l  \
2024-02-09 11:15:59.594  ETHUSDT  2400.56000000  2422.88000000  2399.16000000   

                                     c                v  barcomplete  
2024-02-08 11:15:59.594  2419.79000000  160696.13700000        False
```

Index is the timestamp. I get multiple data rows for the same sym (ETHUSDT price today, yesterday, day before and so on). I want to save coins/ETHUSDT rows into their own separate CSV (ETHUSDT.csv, IDUSDT.csv, etc), with new data rows being appended to those CSVs as they get fetched.

I am using this but its slow:

```
    for coin in df.sym:
        filename = r"{}.csv".format(coin)
        print(filename)
        df['sym'].to_csv(filename, mode='a', header=False)
```

But I just can't get this working properly. Please advise. (I just started learning pandas so please be kind) :)

Answer (score 1):

If multiple rows with different `sym` use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in loop:

```
for name, g in df.groupby('sym'):
    g.to_csv(rf"{name}.csv", mode='a', header=False)
```

Or if get one row or all rows have same `sym` use:

```
df.to_csv(rf"{df['sym'].iat[0]}.csv", mode='a', header=False)
```

Another idea is create one big DataFrame first with `append` and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then write to files:

```
dfs = []
for i in iter:
    #fetch dataframes
    #df = ...
    dfs.append(df)

dfbig = pd.concat(dfs)

for name, g in dfbig.groupby('sym'):
    g.to_csv(rf"{name}.csv", mode='a', header=False)
```